# Two bar magnets taped together in opposite direction (north-south) dropped through a coil

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I conducted an experiment where I have to align two bar magnets so that both ends are “north - south” and tape them together. Then, I have to drop them through the center of a coil of 400 turns

[image]

Results from the voltmeter came out like this.

[image]

But, I don’t understand why there are 3 peaks since when I tape them in the “south-south” or “north-north” position there are only two 2 like below

[image]

Could anyone give an explanation to this ?